# Get date and time separately from created date

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

I want to display created date and time separately in LWC UI. From apex I am returning the created date but not able to get it separately. How can I get date and time separately from created date?

Comment: You can extract these separate components in the LWC JavaScript using standard [JavaScript functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). If, after trying this for yourself, you still have problems, please update this question to show what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you just need the set the date value as a date object. Then you can use any date methods you wish to display the day and hours.

Example:

```
 const createdDateServerValue = “yourValue”;
 const createdDate = new Date(createdDateServerValue);
 const dateValue = createdDate.getDate();
 const hours = createdDate.getHours();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment